# NSIS script to install an exe which requires a Registration Name and Key to be set

Tags: executable, nsis, user-registration

Problem: I need to write a nsi for doing a series of tasks including creating a folder, some IE settings changes, Firewall changes and Installing an exe. The exe to be installed is a licensed copy and requires a Registration Name and Key which I have.

Scenario: I need to perform the same steps after installing the exe in more than 50 computers and I want to make the process free of manual errors.

I successfully wrote all steps but still to find how to install the exe, which prompts me for a Registration Name and Key.

Thanks
lazywizar

Comment: We don't have enough information, you need to figure out where this product stores its registration info if you want to fill it in during install...

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how do you plan to handle the registration name and key, will you need a server to validate the installation ?

Anyway you have to make a custom page and create custom forms in this page. Something like :

```
Page custom CreatePage QuitPage
```

Where CreatePage is a function that creates the page ui

Example:

```
;;In the variables section
var regname_hdl
var regkey_hdl
Var regname_inpt_hdl
var regkey_inpt_hdl
var RegName
var RegKey


Function CreatePage

GetDlgItem $0 $hwndParent 3
EnableWindow $0 0

nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog

${If} $Dialog == error
    Abort
${EndIf}

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 10u "Say something to user"
Pop $Label

${NSD_CreateLabel} 20u 20u 20% 20u "Enter Registration Name "
Pop $regname_inpt_hdl

${NSD_CreateLabel} 20u 40u 20% 20u "Enter Registration Key "
    Pop $regkey_inpt_hdl


    ${NSD_CreateText} 30% 20u 30% 10u ""
    Pop $regname_hdl

    ${NSD_CreatePassword} 30% 40u 30% 10u ""
    Pop $regkey_hdl

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function QuitPage

    ${NSD_GetText} $reg_hdl $2
    ${NSD_GetText} $key_hdl $3
    Push $3
    Push $2
    Pop $RegName
    Pop $RegKey


    ${If} '$2' == ""
          messageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Reg name is empty !"
          Abort
    ${ElseIf} '$3' == ""
         messageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Reg key is empty !"
         Abort
    ${Else}
           System::Alloc 9
           Pop $4
           ;; Here you have to call some procedure to check if reg name and key are valid
           ;; let's say the procedure returns 1 for true and 0 for false and it stores the result in $1

         ${If} $1 == 0
               messageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Installation denied !"
               Abort
         ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    MessageBox MB_OK "Installation allowed !"

    SetPluginUnload manual
    System::Free 0

FunctionEnd
```